# Making pandas code more readable/better organized

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a data analysis project based on Pandas. Data which has to be analyzed is collected from application log files. Log entries are based on sessions, which can be different types (and can have different actions), then each session can have mutliple services (also with different types, actions, etc.). I have transformed log file entries to pandas dataframe and then based on that completed all required calculations. At this moment that's around few hundred different calculations, which are at the end printed to stdout. If anomaly is found that is specifically flagged. So, basic functionality is there, but now after this first phase is done, I'm not happy with readability of the code and it seems to me that there must be a way to make the code better organized.

For example what I have at the moment is:

```
def build(log_file):
    # build dataframe from log file entries
    return df 

def transform(df):
    # transform dataframe (for example based on grouped sessions, services)
    return transformed_df

def calculate(transformed_df):
    # make calculations based on transformed dataframe and print them to stdout
    print calculation1
    print calculation2
    etc.
```

Since there are numerous criteria for filtering data, there is at least 30-40 different data frame filters present. They are used in calculate and in transform functions. In calculate functions I have also some helper functions which perform tasks which can be applied to similar session/service types and then result is based just on filtered dataframe for that specific type. With all these requirements, transformations, filters, I now have more than 1000 lines of code, which as I said, I have a feeling it can be more readable.

My current idea is to have perhaps classes organized like this:

```
class Session:
# main class for sessions (it can be inherited by other session types), also with standradized output for calculations

class Service:
# main class for services (it can be inherited by other service types), also with standradized output for calculations, etc.

class Dataframe
# dataframe class with filters, etc.
```

But I'm not sure if this is good approach. I tried searching here, on github, different blogs, but I didn't find anything which would provide some examples what would be best way to organize code in more than basic panda projects. I would appreciate any suggestion which would put me in the right direction.